# 400 error with HTTPS over self hosted WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, https

I am trying to implement HTTPS on a self hosted windows service.  The service is RESTful (or tries to be).  The service using regular HTTP works fine.  But when I switch to HTTPS, it does not, any HTTPS request I send to that port returns a 400 error and no logging/information.

I looked at this reference  https://pfelix.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/wcf-web-api-self-hosting-https-and-http-basic-authentication/

and especially this one. (James Osborne).    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https.aspx

Using the later, I was able to bind a cert to a port and using his test console and app, communicate via HTTPS.  But that app has a data contract on both client and server, whereas for me I want to send HTTPS requests using a web browser, so that doesn't quite work.

In a nutshell I want to call my test service over HTTPS and return "SUCCESS" in the payload/browser window, and instead I'm getting a 400 error without any details.  I am pretty sure the cert is bound to the port since I used a test server/client on that port over hTTPS and it works.

Here is my server code.

```
private void StartWebService() 
{
    Config.ReadConfig();
    String port = Config.ServicePort;
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Listening on port" + port);

    //BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    //binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;


    // THESE LINES FOR HTTPS
    Uri httpsUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:" + port + "/");
    host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(WebService), httpsUrl);
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

    // THIS IS FOR NORMAL HTTP
    //Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:" + port + "/");
    //host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(WebService), httpUrl); 
    //var binding = new WebHttpBinding(); // NetTcpBinding();

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(iContract), binding, "");
    ServiceDebugBehavior stp = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
    stp.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

    host.Open();

}
```

and here is the WebService

```
class WebService : iContract
{

    public string TestMethod()
    {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

and here is the iContract

```
   [ServiceContract]
    interface iContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string TestMethod();

        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            UriTemplate = "HelloWorld",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        Stream HelloWorld();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BasicHttpBinding wont work with REST service. Use WebHttpBinding like you have used it with your HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was the right thing to fix.  Works now.